# Code a page view counter using cookies, PHP, etc

Tags: php

I found this code from a YouTube tutorial on the same subject. Can't seem to get it to work at all. The error I'm getting now is this

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 13

Anyone know what's wrong with this code? I'm *very* new to PHP. I just about got my head around HTML and CSS with a dash of JS, so spare me if it's something very simple.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",`unique_visitors`);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `unique_visitors` WHERE `date`='$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(!isset($_COOKIE['visitor'])){
$time = strtotime('next day 00:00');
setcookie('visitor','hey',$time);
}
if($result->num_rows==0){
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `unique_visitors` (`date`,`ip`)
VALUES ('$date','$userIP')";

mysqli_query($conn,$insertQuery);

}else{
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();

  if(!isset($_COOKIE['visitor'])){
  $newIP = "$row[ip]";
        if(!preg_match('/'.$userIP.'/',$newIP)){
            $newIP.= " $userIP";
        }
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE `unique_visitors` SET `ip` = '$newIP', 
`views`=`views`+1 WHERE `date`='$date'";

        mysqli_query($conn,$updateQuery);
  }

}
```

Comment: Is the last argument of `mysqli_connect()` enclosed in backticks (`\` `) in you code too or is it just a typo you did when you put the code here? If you have them in the code then read about the [PHP Execution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) and use apostrophes (`'`) or quotes (`"`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL on **line 6** is probably wrong. So **$result** variable is not *mysqli_query* object.

Try to add this snippet **after line 7** to find out whats wrong here.

```
if($result === false)
{
   die("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Read some [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp) about *mysqli_error* function

### UPDATED

This will solve your problem. Set correct variables. You are using Table name on $db_name place.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$db_hostname", "$db_username", "$db_password", "$db_name") or die("db connect error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i added the line in after line 7 and it came back saying no database selected

Comment: edited `unique_visitors` (name of my database) to "unique_visitors" and it shot this back at me... Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'unique_visitors' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 20

Comment: So check if you are using correct name of database. And use a little bit better syntax for your connection - `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "unique_visitors") or die("db connect error: ".mysqli_connect_error());`

Comment: And your database has same name like table of unique_visitors? In mysqli_connect you have to use Database name instead of Table name.

Comment: ah thanks alot mate! being new to php i didnt realise that the table name wasnt the database name lol, works like a charm now

Comment: Nice, check my answer please. Glad to help you.